# Making GUI into applet

Tags: swing, user-interface, applet, jframe, actionlistener

Hey everyone for my research assignment I need to make my GUI program into an applet but I can't seem to make it work, heres my work:

public class BookCentre extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

```
private CardLayout cardManager;
private JPanel deck;
private JButton controls[];
private String names[] = { "Input", "Processing", "Display"};

public BookCentre(){
    super( "CardLayout" );
    Container container = getContentPane();
    deck = new JPanel();
    cardManager = new CardLayout(); 
    deck.setLayout( cardManager );  
    deck.add( card1Panel(), "c1" );
    deck.add( card2Panel(), "c2" );
    deck.add( card3Panel(), "c3" );
    JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
    buttons.setLayout( new GridLayout( 3, 1 ) );
    controls = new JButton[ names.length ];
    for ( int count = 0; count < controls.length; count++ ) {
        controls[ count ] = new JButton( names[ count ] );
        controls[ count ].addActionListener( this );
        buttons.add( controls[ count ] );
        container.add( buttons, BorderLayout.WEST );
        container.add( deck, BorderLayout.CENTER );
        setSize( 700, 500 );
        setVisible( true );}
```

}

```
public JPanel card1Panel(){ 
    JPanel card1 = new JPanel();
card1.setLayout(null);
        Insets insets = card1.getInsets();
        card1.setSize(600, 300);

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel( "Enter Customer Information");
Dimension size1 = label1.getPreferredSize();
label1.setBounds(230, 5, size1.width, size1.height);

    JLabel label1a = new JLabel( "Customer Name:");
Dimension size1a = label1a.getPreferredSize();
label1a.setBounds(1, 65, size1a.width, size1a.height);

    JTextField userinput = new JTextField("");
Dimension size1b = label1a.getPreferredSize();
userinput.setBounds(265, 65, size1b.width, size1b.height);
String text = userinput.getText();

JLabel label1b = new JLabel( "Choose exactly three books: use CTRL Or SHIFT");
Dimension size1c = label1b.getPreferredSize();
label1b.setBounds(1, 110, size1c.width, size1c.height);

String[] selection = {"Deitel-Java How to Program", "Horstmann-Big Java", "Lewis-Software Solutions",  "Staugaard-Java for IS", "Sun-Core Java", "Hamilton-JDBC", "Jackson-Java By Example", "Riley-The Object of Java",  "Geary-Graphic Java", "Santry-Advanced Java2", "Bishop-Java Gently", "Wigglesworth-Advanced Java", "Liang-Intro to Java", "Lambert-Java"};
JList books = new JList(selection);
books.setVisibleRowCount(5);
books.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
Dimension size1d = books.getPreferredSize();
books.setBounds(230, 150, size1d.width, size1d.height);
add(new JScrollPane (books));

JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");
Dimension size1e = submit.getPreferredSize();
submit.setBounds(100, 425, 400, size1e.height);



    card1.add(submit);
    card1.add(books);
    card1.add(userinput);
    card1.add(label1);
    card1.add(label1a);
    card1.add(label1b);

return card1;
```

}

```
public JPanel card2Panel(){
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel( "Processing", SwingConstants.CENTER );
    JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
    card2.add( label2 );
    return card2;
```

}

```
public JPanel card3Panel(){
    JLabel label3 = new JLabel( "card three" );
    JPanel card3 = new JPanel();
    card3.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );  
    card3.add( new JButton( "North" ), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    card3.add( new JButton( "West" ), BorderLayout.WEST );
    card3.add( new JButton( "East" ), BorderLayout.EAST );
    card3.add( new JButton( "South" ), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    card3.add( label3, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    return card3;
```

}

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )   {




    if ( event.getSource() == controls[ 0 ] )    
        cardManager.first( deck ); 

    else if ( event.getSource() == controls[ 1 ] )    
        cardManager.show( deck, "c2" ); 

    else if ( event.getSource() == controls[ 2 ] )
        cardManager.last( deck );
```

}

```
public static void main( String args[] )   {
    BookCentre cardDeckDemo = new BookCentre();
    cardDeckDemo.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
```

}
}

***for the line:***

```
public class BookCentre extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
```

I tried replacing  "JFrame" with "Applet" but I start to get numerous errors throughout my code.

Comment: Please indent code (using a logical and consistent method). I find that mess unreadable. As to the GUI, a better option is probably not to do any conversion, but launch the working (presumably `JFrame` based) app. from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: *"I  tried replacing "JFrame" with "Applet" but I start to get numerous errors throughout my code."*  1) You do realize that Swing offers a `JApplet`, right?  2) How do you expect anybody to solve **any** of the 'numerous errors' when you do not copy/paste them into the post?

Answer (score 0):

Emm... Question is quite unclear :S But here are some tips

- A) Replace JFrame with JApplet
- B) replace main method with the applet init(){} method
- C) Compile project
- D) write jnlp to start it
- E) write correct html launcher

... and if it doesn't help please show us the stack trace you get thrown during compilation or running because currently the question does contain less problem details